# Why is the UI thread blocked when work is done on a separate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my app, I have a ViewPager with +/- 10 pages. When the app is first opened, all the pages are instantiated and immediately begin to load data to display. Each page (which are fragments) creates an AsyncTask to query a database and populate itself with the appropriate data. Here's the problem: even though the work is being done on separate threads, the UI stops updating during the database queries (which are done sequentially, and take 1-3 seconds total). This happens both on my Nexus 5 and a crappy old Samsung phone, so I know the problem is not that the hardware just can't keep up.

So ultimately, I'm wondering why the UI thread is blocked by work done on a background thread. My understanding of threading was that doing work on one would not block the other for an extended period of time. If my understanding is wrong, please explain how. Thanks in advance.

I don't think code is required here, but if it is, let me know and I will post the relevant portions.

Comment: Is the UI thread actually blocked?  Or do **background** operations simply take longer than you expect?  Android recently started by default **running all AsyncTasks sequentially on a single thread** (as people were making consistency mistakes) but you can specify otherwise.

Comment: In the action bar, I have an indefinite ProgressBar to show that things are loading. It stops animating immediately after the first database query begins and starts animating again immediately after the last database query completes (I know when those things occur thanks to LogCat prints). I also cannot scroll between tabs, open the overflow menu, or interact with my app's UI at all. If it matters, I'm running the AsyncTasks in parallel on the default AsyncTask executor.

Comment: If you are saying that the UI thread itself is blocked, then find out what it is waiting on (for example, keep hitting buttons until it ANR's and then pull and examine the trace).  Do you have any locks or use of *synchronized* where an AsyncTask could lock out the UI?  Do you call the .get() method of an AsyncTask from the UI?

Comment: I never call `get()`. I do use locks to control access to the database, but those are all acquired and released during `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 3):

> It stops animating immediately after the first database query begins and starts animating again immediately after the last database query completes

It is possible, then, you are not doing the work on a background thread that you think you are. You may be doing the work on the main application thread.

Traceview can help you identify what you are doing on the various threads, and `StrictMode` can help you with obvious problems (disk I/O and network I/O on the main application thread).

In this case, you may be getting caught by how you are doing your work:

> Each page (which are fragments) creates an AsyncTask to query a database and populate itself with the appropriate data.

If you are doing your query in `doInBackground()` but are not touching the resulting `Cursor` *also* in `doInBackground()`, the query actually wasn't done yet. The `Cursor` is a `SQLiteCursor`, and it lazy-executes the query when the data is first used. This is another one of those "really cool ideas that just plain suck in how we do things nowadays". A workaround is to call `getCount()` on the `Cursor` while you are in `doInBackground()`, to ensure that the query actually is executed on the background thread.

Comment: I do everything I possibly can during `doInBackground()`, which amounts to querying the database and constructing a `ListAdapter` with the resulting data. The only thing I do in `onPostExecute()` is set the adapter of my `ListView` to the one I created in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: I also did try enabling strict mode in the Developer Options, but the screen never flashed once in my app.

Comment: @NathanWalters: Then I suggest perhaps cracking open Traceview and seeing what a method trace shows you. Note that a frozen `ProgressBar` with an *emulator* may indicate a problem with the Host GPU emulation, but you appear to be having the problem with hardware. "I do use locks to control access to the database" -- you may want to get rid of those. `SQLiteDatabase` already has locks for thread control, so long as all threads are using the same `SQLiteDatabase` instance.

Comment: I'll give Traceview a shot and see if anything interesting comes up. Thanks for that advice about locks.

Comment: I don't have much experience in interpreting Traceview logs, but to me the results are just confusing. If the documentation is correct, the black lines in "main" mean that the UI thread is updating periodically, like it should, which is not what I'm seeing in practice. Could your experienced eyes shed any light on this? http://imgur.com/ttQT09X

Comment: @NathanWalters: Yes, it would appear that the main application thread is not being blocked. It's not getting tons of time between 1.4 and 2.6 seconds from the start, but more than enough to process basic touch events. See if there are warning messages in LogCat from Choreographer complaining about lots of dropped frames. If there are none, then perhaps the issue is that you've opened up some other window (dialog with transparent contents?) that has stolen user input away from your activity.

Comment: I've checked for Choreographer warnings before, but I never see any warnings about dropped frames, or any warnings at all, for that matter. I know that there's nothing blocking input because if I swipe rapidly back and forth on the screen while it's "frozen", a frame will be drawn every second or so that shows that my ViewPager has received the input and scrolled a bit.

Comment: @NathanWalters: Your main application thread must not be blocked (otherwise the `ViewPager` would not work). There's little question that "Async Task #3" is doing lotsa work, which isn't helping your case, but I would have expected Choreographer dropped-frames complaints if it were keeping the CPU from processing the main application thread. All I can suggest is try to "lighten the load" of what that background thread is doing, and see if that helps. For example, comment the whole thing out, see if it improves, then slowly reintroduce the background work.

Comment: I'll see what I can do. The thread is already doing pretty much the bare minimum of what it can while continuing to function, so that'll be tricky. Thanks for trying to help.